# Powerbuilder Get objects of Nested Datawindows

Tags: nested, powerbuilder, datawindow

I have a datawindow dw_1

Inside there are 3 datawindows (nested): dw_1, dw_2, dw_3

I want a way to get the objects of the 3 datawindows.

This does not work (it prompts *Incompatible property Object for type datawindowchild*) because it is a Nested and not a Composite.

I cannot work out the appropriate dot notation

```
 datawindowchild ldwc_report1
dw_1.GetChild("dw_1",ldwc_report1)

li_col_idx = 1
ls_objects = ldwc_report1.object.datawindow.objects
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To naswer my question: Edit Source and set Processing = 5